# If a function f is continuous and differentiable on its domain, is f' differentiable on its domain?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Since $f$ is continuous and differentiable, we can deduce that $f'$ is also continuous, but we don't know if it is differentiable.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: $f'$ need not be continuous.  $f'$ does have the intermediate value property.

Comment: Solve what?  As you said, knowing that $f'(x)$ is continuous does not mean it is differentiable.  Take $f(x)=x^{4/3}$ for example.  $f'(x)$ is continuous but not differentiable. (the deriviative, $f''(x)$ is undefined at $0$).

Comment: @lulu In fact, there are functions that are everywhere continuous and nowhere differentiable [See Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x^2, & x\le 0,\\ x^2, &x>0.\end{cases}$$ It is continuous and differentiable. Moreover

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}-2x, & x\le 0,\\ 2x, &x>0,\end{cases}$$ is continuous. But it is not differentiable at zero. Note that $f'(x)=2|x|.$

Comment: In fact, there are functions that are everywhere continuous and nowhere differentiable [See Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ defined by

$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x})& x\neq 0\\ 0  & x=0\end{cases}$

so

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}3x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})-x\cos(\frac{1}{x}) &x\neq 0\\
0& x=0\end{cases}$$

$f$ and $f'$ are continuous at $ \mathbb R$, but $f'$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, since $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ doesn't exist.